# How to show HTML page contents in a custom layout in Android

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I want to show a web page to a custom layout in Android, like how they show blogs in pulse news android app or in Flipboard.

I have tried to perse the html of the page to extract the texts,but was unsuccessful. Can anyone please tell me how can i do that? Thanks

Comment: you need to implement an 'rss reader' you will get the text from the xml tags and show it as you want

Comment: yes but i also want to show the details of the blog/news..xml tags only gives a smaller description.right?

Comment: I'm not sure of the amount of information that xml tags will give you, but I'm sure that flipboard works as an rss reader, so it's interesting to do a little research about that.

Answer (score 0):

Most "custom layouts" are just CSS. There is an amazing amount you can do with this. If you want a little more control, you might try using javascript or jQuery, since they have built in many of the features needed for DOM manipulation and customizing the experience. If it is in-app, then you could easily include a webkit frame with the content.

If you want to parse the HTML and create your own layout with some server-side or in-app technology, though, I'd recommend looking at BeautifulSoup, a python module that allows manipulation of HTML.